# remove duplicates with conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data chart that i update every week. when i add new data i need to delete the duplicate data. but there are conditions, rules what to delete and what not.
in the pictures i explain.
basically i need to manually see if the new data (in yellow) has the same numbers,names,dates and values.

if all data above is the same then its a simple delete duplicate. but if there are some data that isn't the same as the old data i need to keep it. and i also need to keep the data that has the most hours out of the duplicates.(column c)

geez..it sounds crazy but i manged to record a macro (whats in the pictures)

```
Sub Macro20() ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("excel").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("excel").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A80"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("excel").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G2:G80"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("excel").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:P80")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$80").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 7), _
    Header:=xlYes  End Sub
```

the problem here is that is dosent keep the highest hour, and that the range isnt dynamic

and i made a code - only that the code dosent keep the biggest number in hours.
im so close!! what am i missing?

```
Sub DeleteTheDoops()
Dim RowNdx As Long 
For RowNdx = Range("A1:G1").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
If Cells(RowNdx, "A").Value = Cells(RowNdx - 1, "A").Value Then
 If Cells(RowNdx, "F").Value = Cells(RowNdx - 1, "F").Value Then
    If Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value <= Cells(RowNdx - 1, "C").Value Then
    If Cells(RowNdx, "E").Value <= Cells(RowNdx - 1, "E").Value Then
       Rows(RowNdx).Delete
    Else
        Rows(RowNdx - 1).Delete
    End If
End If 
End If 
End IfNext RowNdx
End Sub
```

im kinda lost. hope i was clear. thank you !!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the code you wrote is pretty close. I'd just make a few modifications. I think you'd be best to have two loops so you can always compare what is in the first loop with what is in the second.

```
Sub DeleteTheDoops()
Dim RowNdx As Long 
Dim RowNdx2 As Long
Dim FR as Long
FR = Range("A1:G1").End(xlDown).Row 'Freeze this row
For RowNdx = FR To 2 Step -1
    For RowNdx2 = FR to 2 Step -1
        'From what I can tell, you are interested when A, E and F are 
        'equal and when C is smallest, so ...
        If RowNdx <> RowNdx2 and _
           Cells(RowNdx, "A").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "A").Value and _
           Cells(RowNdx, "F").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "F").Value and _
           Cells(RowNdx, "E").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "E").Value and _
           Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value >= Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value Then
               Rows(RowNdx2).Delete
        End If
    Next RowNdx2
Next RowNdx
End Sub
```

Comment: its good!!!!
but one thing. with the max number, it works with most but there are some areas where it dosnt

Comment: Do you have my edit in, `FR = Range("A1:G1").End(xlDown).Row 'Freeze this row`?

Comment: I think I know what happened. I made a tiny edit to my code that should do the trick, but please do tell me if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

***Best approach:***

Your best way to do so is by using a [dictionary](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-dictionary-arrays-and-other-data-structures/) and, if the elements repeats, erase it. This kind of approach may save you a lot of time if you need to modify parameters later on, as well in the code execution itself. The dictionary itself is designed to manage data structures like this.

***Code approach:***

This may give you a nice scope for what you need, suit to your needs.

```
Sub DuplicatedValues()
Dim DictionaryKey As String: DictionaryKey = ""
Dim DictionaryForDups As Dictionary
Dim CounterCriteriaForDup As Long
Dim TotalRows As Long: TotalRows = Sheets("MySheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim CounterRows As Long

    For CounterRows = 2 To TotalRows 'title is 1
    'Counter criteria is based on the column within the row
    For CounterCriteriaForDup = 2 To Sheets("MySheet").UsedRange.Columns.Count 'you may use another approach to get last column if needed
        Select Case CounterCriteriaForDup
            Case 1, 3, 5, 6 'Column numbers to get criteria to say it's duplicated A=1, C=3, ...
            DictionaryKey = DictionaryKey & Trim(Cells(CounterRows, CounterCriteriaForDup).Value)
         End Select
    Next CounterCriteriaForDup
    If Not DictionaryForDups.Exists(DictionaryKey) Then ' 1. If Not DictionaryForDups.Exists(DictionaryKey)
                Call DictionaryForDups.Add(DictionaryKey, CounterRows - 1)
    Else ' 1. If Not DictionaryForDups.Exists(DictionaryKey)
        Rows(CounterRows).Delete
        CounterRows = CounterRows - 1
        End If ' 1. If Not DictionaryForDups.Exists(DictionaryKey)
        DictionaryKey = vbNullString
    Next CounterRows
End Sub
```

***Further comments:***

Data structures like this are hard to deal at first, give a read for other useful data management varaibles, such as arrays, collections in the link gave above.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i got it.
i first will delete all diplicates that are the same (1st,2nd,3rd)
and then ill delete the remaining will the lowest number

thank you @Matt Cremeens

```
Sub DeleteTheDoops()
Dim RowNdx As LongDim RowNdx2 As LongFor RowNdx = Range("A1:G1").End(xlDown).Row To 3 Step -1
For RowNdx2 = RowNdx - 1 To 2 Step -1 'Begin at one above RowNdx
    'when A, E and F are equal so just delete duplicates as normanl
    If Cells(RowNdx, "A").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "A").Value And _
       Cells(RowNdx, "g").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "g").Value And _
       Cells(RowNdx, "f").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "f").Value And _
       Cells(RowNdx, "h").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "h").Value And _
       Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value Then
           Rows(RowNdx2).Delete End If 'now delete duplicates that have a smaller number in column c
    If Cells(RowNdx, "A").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "A").Value And _
        Cells(RowNdx, "g").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "g").Value And _
        Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value >= Cells(RowNdx - 1, "C").Value Then
           Rows(RowNdx).Delete End If

   Next RowNdx2 Next RowNdx End Sub
```